# Spring Rest API with WebApp

Tags: java, spring, rest

I just followed this tutorial 
https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/

And it's really interesting but I am wondering how can I create the same app without using spring boot, I want to deploy it in a tomcat web container.

In addiction I want also to add a context path to that the app will run on localhost:8080/appName/app and the api will run on localhost:8080/appName/web

thank you!

Comment: try to see this https://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part1.html

Comment: Do you want to deploy it in a Tomcat container AND not to use Spring-boot? Because if the problem is just to deploy it in Tomcat you can also pack the Spring-boot application as war instead of a jar using "spring-boot-maven-plugin" and deploy it in Tomcat without any problem.

Comment: Ok maybe the question is somehow wrong, the fact is that i want to deploy  my web application backend using the `CrudRepository<T,ID>` and `PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>` Interface to speed up my dvelopment and avoid coding lots of boilerplate code.
The frontend will be developed using Reat + Weback + redux.
I also think that spring boot adds lots of useless code (a web container implementation) to my app since it must be deployed into a container, isn't it?

Comment: I can't get the connection between using CrudRepository and not using Spring-boot. CrudRepository is part of spring-data that is included in spring-boot core. Spring-boot is meant to reduce boilerplate and it doesn't contains a web container, it just has an embedded Tomcat or Jetty that you can use or not (using it actually speed up your development and deploy, because you just create the jar and run it, without set up and configure Tomcat by yourself). The way you wrote your application, using or not interfaces like CrudRepository, is not related to using or not spring-boot framework.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, could you provide me an example or tutorial of how can I deploy my app in tomcat? What about the context path, can I define it both for api and frontend?

Comment: @LorenzoDeFrancesco: you can take a look at this link from the SpringBoot documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file

Answer (score 1):

You can you Spring mvc

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig{
   //
}
```

@EnableWebMvc annotation does a number of useful things – specifically, in the case of REST, it detects the existence of Jackson and JAXB 2 on the classpath
 and automatically creates and registers default JSON and XML converters.

The @Controller is the central artifact in the entire Web Tier of the RESTful API. For the purpose of this post, the controller is modeling a simple REST resource – Foo:

```
    @Controller
     @RequestMapping( value = "/foos" )
        class FooController{
           @Autowired
           IFooService service;

           @RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET )
           @ResponseBody
           public List< Foo > findAll(){
              return service.findAll();
           }

           @RequestMapping( value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET )
           @ResponseBody
           public Foo findOne( @PathVariable( "id" ) Long id ){
              return RestPreconditions.checkFound( service.findOne( id ) );
           }

           @RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.POST )
           @ResponseStatus( HttpStatus.CREATED )
           @ResponseBody
           public Long create( @RequestBody Foo resource ){
              Preconditions.checkNotNull( resource );
              return service.save( resource );
           }

           @RequestMapping( value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT )
           @ResponseStatus( HttpStatus.OK )
           public void update( @PathVariable( "id" ) Long id, @RequestBody Foo resource ){
              Preconditions.checkNotNull( resource );
              RestPreconditions.checkNotNull( service.findOne( resource.getId() ) );
//update logic
              service.save( resource );
           }

           @RequestMapping( value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE )
           @ResponseStatus( HttpStatus.OK )
           public void delete( @PathVariable( "id" ) Long id ){
              service.delete( id );
           }

        }
```

The Controller implementation is non-public – this is because it doesn’t need to be. Usually, the controller is the last in the chain of dependencies – it receives HTTP requests from the Spring front controller (the DispathcerServlet) and simply delegates them forward to a service layer. If there is no use case where the controller has to be injected or manipulated through a direct reference, then I prefer not to declare it as public.

The request mappings are straightforward – as with any controller, the actual value of the mapping as well as the HTTP method are used to determine the target method for the request. @RequestBody will bind the parameters of the method to the body of the HTTP request, whereas @ResponseBody does the same for the response and return type. They also ensure that the resource will be marshalled and unmarshalled using the correct HTTP converter. Content negotiation will take place to choose which one of the active converters will be used, based mostly on the Accept header, although other HTTP headers may be used to determine the representation as well.
Here is helpful [tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/building-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-and-java-based-configuration)

**Spring Data**
Lets see `IFooService`, it is used in our controller for basic `curd operation`

IFooService.java

```
public interface IFooService extends CrudRepository<Foo, Long> {
}
```

Spring data save our life, Spring Data is a high level SpringSource project whose purpose is to unify and ease the access to different kinds of persistence stores, both relational database systems and NoSQL data stores.

Here `IFooService` extends the CrudRepository, where we passing the Foo as a entity and Long as a Foo id type in generic argument.
If you will see in `FooController` IFooService is autowire and we are using there  following methods :

> findAll,findOne,save, delete

We dont have provided the implementation of these methods in  `IFooService`
, actually, these method is come from `CrudRepository` means curd operation is handling by spring data which save out lot of the time [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html) is `CrudRepository` doc also you can learn lot about spring data from [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/)

Comment: That is really nice implementation but I must write lots of boilerplate code this way. The fact is that I want to expose my API using the `CrudRepository<T,ID>` and  `PagingAndSortingRepository<T, ID extends Serializable>` Interface to speed up my dvelopment.

Comment: @LorenzoDeFrancesco yes CrudRepository is part of spring data, I have updated the service  part in my answer where Spring data come in picture, please have a look

Comment: Great, I see it!
But what about the controller, is it possible to expose my service in a standard way without writing the controller?

Comment: You can use REST with Java (JAX-RS) using Jersey with spring data or Spring provide @RestController for Rest api so you can also use RestController with spring data 
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html